# cakephp jquery validator

Tags: jquery, cakephp, jquery-validate

I am trying to use jquery validator in a cakephp project.There is probem with jquery
I think,something wrong with selector id of my form..I can not even alert any message inside.
I am completely a fresher.

I used following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){        $('#UserQuickCompanyRegisterForm').validate({
       rules: {
            "data['User']['email']": {
               required: true,
               email: true
           }
        }
       });        });
```

and my form is like this.

```
echo $form->create('User', array('action' => 'quick_company_register','inputDefaults'=> array('label'=>false)));
```

and it outputs somthing like below.

```
<form id="UserQuickCompanyRegisterForm" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="/cityportal/index.php/users/quick_company_register" novalidate="novalidate">.
```

what i am doing wrong...thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Cake are you using? In 2.0 at least, the field names are like this: `data[User][email]` (no single quotes). Also, the way you are applying the validation methods doesn't seem to conform to the documentation here http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation -- assuming that is the plugin you're using.

Comment: i am using cake 1.2 stable.Now i got this code working and...I have this problem that equalto rule is not working in it..And if i am doing any wrong please let me know...I jope i am following docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation  methods..follwing are my codes            "data[User][password]": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
        },
        "data[User][password1]": {
            required: true,
            equalTo: 'data[User][password]',
            minlength: 6,
        },

Comment: Thnks for your try.I was making a problem that using element id instead of element id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its solved.I was making mistake with element id.Instead of id i used name attrbute."Silly me".After a ;ong fat burning hour i got thit following code wrking

```
<script type="text/javascript">     $(function(){           $.validator.addMethod("alphanum", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9/_]+$/i.test(value);
        }, "Username must contain only alphanumeric.");

       jQuery.validator.addMethod("exactlength", function(value, element, param) {       return this.optional(element) || value.length == param;        }, jQuery.format("Please enter exactly {0} characters.")); 
             $('#UserQuickCompanyRegisterForm').validate({          debug: false,
       errorClass: "authError",
       errorElement: "span",
        rules: {    
            "data[User][username]": {
               required: true,
               alphanum: true,
               minlength: 4,
               maxlength: 30
           },
           "data[User][password]": {
               required: true,
               minlength: 6
           },
           "data[User][password1]": {
               required: true,
               equalTo: "data[User][password]"
           },
           "data[User][first_name]": {
               required: true,
               maxlength: 30,
               alphanum: true
           },
           "data[User][second_name]": {
               required: true,
               maxlength: 30,
               alphanum: true
           },
           "data[ZIP][zipcode]": {
               required: true,
               number:true, 
                exactlength: 5
           },

            "data[User][email]": {
               required: true,
               email: true
           },
           "data[User][telephone]": {
               number: true,
               exactlength: 10
           }
       },
       highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
        }
       });        });
       </script>
```

Comment: hello @jack please tell me how can i use remote validation, i applied but didnt get the value for username in controller to check the data is present or not